# Overtone Livecoding with Emacs/Slime/Swank/cake - Could not locate overtone.live__init.class

Tags: java, emacs, slime, swank

I am trying to use emacs and slime to connect to swank to live code using Overtone.  I have the whole thing pretty much working, but when i try to run

```
(ns foo
   (:use [overtone.live]
          [overtone.inst.synth]))

(definst bar [] (saw 220))
```

I get the error 'Could not locate overtone/live__inti.class or overtone/live.clj on classpath:'  Which i gather basically means that the class files are not where it is looking for them.  I am not sure what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 6):

**Important note: Slime/Swank/Cake are deprecated means of connecting Overtone and Emacs. Instead, consider using nREPL via Leiningen 2+ and CIDER**

it looks like you haven't got the Overtone jar on the classpath. Things to check:

- You have overtone-X-Y-X.jar in your project's lib directory
- Your project isn't called Overtone (that can cause issues with tools like lein)

Finally, you might want to take a look at this setup video: http://vimeo.com/25190186 which describes the process of getting an Overtone dev environment setup.

Good luck and come join the mailing list and share your thoughts: http://groups.google.com/group/overtone

Comment: Renaming my project to `overtone-project` got me past the "overtone_init.class" error.  But now I'm attempting to fix a missing `clojure/contrib/fcase__init.class` error

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing any contrib references - we removed dependence on contrib when we moved to support Clojure 1.3 back in Overtone 0.4.0. If you move to Overtone 0.5.0, remove all the jars in your project's lib directory, ensure your project is requiring 1.3 and not requiring any contrib libs, then do a `lein deps` and see if you still get the error. Please also consider emailing the mailing list if you're still seeing issues - you're much more likely to get a swift response there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried confirming that overtone is in your java classpath?

```
(System/getProperty "java.class.path")
```

It's most likely a temporary fix, as I'm just getting my feet wet with clojure and overtone, but I included overtone as a global dependecy in my `~/.cake` directory and installed it with:

```
cake deps --global
```

Additionally, I'd reccomend updating to the latest version of `overtone` as it looks like the vimeo link is a few versions behind what is currently reflected on clojars:

http://clojars.org/overtone